# Using tapply or by with non-default settings of a function

Tags: r, if-statement, lapply, tapply

I have been searching Stackoverflow for hours hoping to find something I guessed was self-evident but nobody seemed to have asked (which might mean it is indeed self-evident).

I want to use `tapply` or `by`, to find the first time a specific event occurs in a dataframe (first non-zero value). The way I did this before was via

```
max.col(df, ties.method = c("first"))
```

But somehow this does not work when used in conjunction with either tapply or by. Here's some examplary data

```
FIRM<-as.vector(sample(c("a","b","c","d"),100,replace=T))
MOMENT<-as.vector(sample((1990:1995),100,replace=T))
EVENT<-as.vector(sample(c("x12","x43","x35","y71","y81","xy1","xy67","yy123","xx901"),100,replace=T))
OCCURENCE<-as.vector(sample(c(0,1),100,replace=T))
m<-as.data.frame(cbind(FIRM,MOMENT,EVENT,OCCURENCE))
```

So here is what I tried and did not work

1. `tapply(m[,4],m[,3],max.col)` # This gives just 1s for every EVENT with the length of the resulting vector equal to number of EVENTs mentioned in the dataset
2. `tapply(m[,4],m[,3],max.col(m, ties.method=c("first")))` # Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
   'max.col(m, ties.method = c("first"))' is not a function, character or symbol
   In addition: Warning message: In max.col(m, ties.method = c("first")) : NAs introduced by coercion

Number 2 is really the crux of the problem. For reasons unclear to me, max.col is not recognised as a function once you change the default tie-breaking method (i.e. "random") to to one I need (i.e. "first").

Additionally, I'd want to be able to find the year in which the non-zero occurs.
I think a sensible alternative would be to multiply the MOMENT column with the OCCURENCE column (call that ID) and look for the first non-zero value in ID (for each factor EVENT) keep that ID value and turn the other values into zero

```
m$MOMENT<-as.numeric(as.character(m$MOMENT))
m$OCCURENCE<-as.numeric(as.character(m$OCCURENCE))    
m[,"ID"]<-m$MOMENT * m$OCCURENCE
```

I have tried to code this with a function containing a `when` and `if` statement and using `break` but it does not work

```
tapply(m$ID,m$EVENT, function(x) m$ID[i]<- while (m$ID[i] == 0) {m$ID[i]
                  if (m$ID[i]>0) {m$YEAR[i] && break }})
```

The idea here was to iterate the function over EVENT while m$ID == 0 and then to change the value and break once m$ID > 0. Didn't work...

Any ideas on how to fix this (or much simpler solutions)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FUN` argument of `tapply` must be a function but the code in the question supplies an expression, not a function.  Try this:

```
tapply(m[,4], m[,3], max.col, ties.method =  "first")
```

This will give a logical indicator of the first row in each event which has 1 in the OCCURENCE column and the second line will select those rows:

```
o <- order(m$EVENT, m$MOMENT) # omit this and next line if already ordered
m <- m[o,]

is.first <- ave(m$OCCURENCE == 1, m$EVENT, FUN = function(x) x & !duplicated(x))
m[is.first, ]
```

*REVISED*

- Ordered by event and year.
- Note that if its possible that there are events with only zeros then such events will be omitted entirely from `m[is.first, ]` .

Comment: Thanks G.G This works like a charm once I order the variables according to years. Not sure how the ave function exactly works but it does the trick :)! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve, so here is only some coding advice.

First of all, you need to read `help("tapply")` to lear how to pass arguments to the function that is passed to `tapply`:

```
tapply(m[,4],m[,3],max.col, ties.method="first")
```

However, I doubt this does what you need. Maybe something like this would be useful:

```
m<-data.frame(FIRM,MOMENT,EVENT,OCCURENCE)
#note how I create the data.frame in a different way 
#in order to avoid coercing all columns to factors


tapply(m[,4],m[,3],which.max)
#  x12   x35   x43 xx901   xy1  xy67   y71   y81 yy123 
#    2     1     2     3     1     1     3     1     1 

tapply(m[,4],m[,3],function(x) m[which.max(x), "MOMENT"])
#  x12   x35   x43 xx901   xy1  xy67   y71   y81 yy123 
# 1995  1995  1995  1991  1995  1995  1991  1995  1995
```

Comment: Thanks @Roland, I did not think of the which.max function before. I thought it gave the maximum number and not the first maximum so this works brilliantly as well.

Comment: Hey @Roland, I've been trying to make your solution work but it seems to make errors. The results are different depending on the ordering of the data (which can of course be fixed), and in your example it gives xx901 as 1991 for instance which is false, it should be 1992, x43 is giving 1995 but it should be 1990... This might relate to how which.max is looking for the first maximum, i.e. the starting position within the subgroup determined by the factor m[,3]... not sure. Anyway your colleagues suggestion via ave function works perfectly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Of course this depends on the order. I understood that you asked for the first position in the data.frame and not for the first year. If you want the first year, you need to order the data.frame or use a different approach.

Comment: Hi @Roland, that's what I thought as well. Should have been clearer in my question. Yet, even if I order the df, the result is still incorrect though...